# How to convert base64 color image to grayscale image using javascript

Tags: javascript

can I know how to convert base64 color image to grayscale image using javascript? I'm using the Cordova camera plugin to take pictures and need to save base64 data in the database as a grayscale image.

Comment: Why you want to do the color conversion in javascript? For image manipulation purpose, server side languages are suitable and easy to do. Whatever server lang you are used, try to do it there. C#, Java, Php all have very good support of image manipulation.

Comment: I want to reduce the image size below 1MB, that is why I need to try to convert the image to grayscale. The Cordova camera output image size is around 2MB to 5MB.

Comment: try camanjs or fabricjs. These two libraries has image manipulation features on client side using canvas.

Answer (score 0):

[EX on Codepen](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/BRMxXy)

```
 context.filter = 'grayscale(100%)'
```